# Scala: mutable.Map[Any, mutable.Map[Any, IndexedSeq[Any]] issue

Tags: scala, mutable

I have a tiny problem when trying to put an item in my second mutable map.
My objective: gather some elements located in many different xml files, and organise them in the hierarchy they belong (the files are an unstructured mess, with categories being given in seemingly no logical order).
Those elements are: the level in hierarchy of the category (1 - x, 1 is top level) as iLevel, the category code as catCode, its name, and if need be, the name of its parents (all names located in namesCategories).

```
val categoryMap = mutable.Map.empty[Int, mutable.Map[String, IndexedSeq[String]]]

...
//Before: search in a first file links to other files
// for each category file found, will treat it and store it for further treatement.
matches.foreach{f =>
        ....
       //Will search for a specific regex, and for each matches store what we are interested in
      matchesCat.foreach{t =>
        sCat = t.replaceFirst((system_env + """\S{4}"""), "")
        //iLevel given by the number of '/' remaining in the string
        iLevel = sCat.count(_ == '/')
        //reset catCode and namesCategories
        catCode = ""
        namesCategories.clear()
   //Search and extract the datas from sCat using premade regex patterns
        sCat match {
          case patternCatCode(codeCat) => catCode = s"$codeCat"
        }
        //remove the category code to prepare to extract names
        sCat.replace(patternCatCode.toString(), "")
        //extract names
        do {
          sCat match {
            case patternCatNames(name) => namesCategories += s"$name"
          }
          sCat.replace(patternCatNames.toString(), "")
        }while(sCat!="")

        // create the level entry if it doesn't exist
        if(!(categoryMap.contains(iLevel))) {
            categoryMap.put(iLevel, mutable.Map.empty[String, IndexedSeq[String]])
        }

        //Try to add my cat code and the names, which must be in order for further treatment, to my map
        categoryMap(iLevel).put(catCode, namesCategories.clone())


      }
    }
  }
```

Problem:
Type mismatch, expected: IndexedSeq[String], actual: mutable.Builder[String, IndexedSeq[String]]

As Travis Brown kindly noted, I have an issue with a type mismatch, but I don't know how to fix that and get the general idea working.

I tried to keep the code to only what is relevant here, if more is needed I'll edit again.

Any  tips?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is not clear what you're asking? what are iLevel, catCode and namesCategories?

Comment: The compiler message seems pretty clear to me: you said you wanted `IndexedSeq[String]` for values in the inner map, but you're trying to put a `Builder` you made with `IndexedSeq.newBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I edited to give a more accurate idea of what I try to achieve here. I tried to change IndexedSeq.newBuilder, but then I just get some other errors. Any more input is welcome.